# PHP library for keeping your site Indexed by Google Bing etc

Tags: php, url, indexing

I need some library which would be able to keep my urls Indexed and described. So I want to say to it something like

Index this new url "www.bla-bla.com/new_url" with some key words

or something like that. And I want to be soure that If I told my lib about my new URL Google and others will 100% find it As soon as possible and people will be able to find this URL on the web.

Do you know any such libs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any librarys that will achieve this but I think you need to do some reading on Search Engine Optimisation.  From my understanding (and please correct me if I am wrong) when a Google Bot comes to your website to index it, it will check for a file called sitemap.xml.  In this file you define properties as follows;

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.myhost.com/mypage.html</loc>
<lastmod>YYYY-DD-MM</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```

As far as I know, you can not specifiy particular keywords for a particular page.  The use of META tags can to "some" (arguably) extent influence this.  The main influence will be the actual content of the page.

I would recommend the use of Google's "Webmaster Tools" which will give you feedback/errors about the indexing of your site.  You can [Add your site to google](http://www.google.co.uk/addurl/) and join a queue for indexing.

There are several Automated Sitemap Generators, which I have had no experience with so can not comment on these.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that a Yahoo Bot will look for a file called urllist.txt which is just a text doucment of URLs to index.  

A good book to read on the topic is "Professional Search Engine Optimisation with PHP" from the "Wrox" series.  Covers lots of different aspects that will influence your Search Engine Ranking and Click Through Rate (the number of times that someone clicks through to your website form a Search Engine Listing)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to (immediately and on-demand) manipulate the search results in any search engine. It will always take at least a week for your site to be indexed (maybe even longer).

Comment: So tell my why StackOverflow Q's I can find in google after 5 minuts I posted them?

Comment: changefreq can have a value of always, hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly or never (Source http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php).  This is an indication to Google how often it should crawl and index your site.  but does not guarantee that it will index your every hour for instance.  I would have thought Google recognises the fact that this website is constantly being updated and therefore indexes more often compared to a personal website.  If you set hourly as your frequency, Google will be able to determine if this is true or not and will affect your index and ranking accordingly.