# Why is Yahoo Indexing Bot considered as "evil"?

Tags: indexing, search-engine, bots

After reading and commenting on this question [PHP Library for Keeping your site index by Google, Bing, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557523/php-library-for-keeping-your-site-indexed-by-google-bing-etc/2557567#2557567), I was curious to look at StackOverFlow's [sitemap](http://www.stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml).  This returned a 404 error which I am guessing is just a protected page by determining if your are a Index Bot or simply doesnt exists.

This then lead me to look at the [robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) for StackOverFlow.  I was surprised to see the comment "Yahoo bot is evil" along with a couple other Indexing bots (Spinn3r and KSCrawler) .  I am unfamilular with Spinn3r and KSCrawler but my question is, why are these bots (particular Yahoo) considered as evil?  Surely any and all indexing of any Search Engine is a good thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are very aggressive bots that do not throttle requests and can bring a site down.

See [this](http://mobility.mobi/showthread.php?12985-very-agressive-yahoo-bot&s=75e6dfaaaf4f2c4276714640301d0600&p=55831#post55831) forum thread for an example for the yahoo bot.